# Filter the columns of a 2d numpy array by only one line

Tags: python, numpy

If this question should be a repost, I'd be glad if somebody could point me to another question, but unfortunately I didn't find anything relatable.

I have a 2d numy array and I'd like to separate them by the median of one line.
The function I'd like to write would look something like this:

```
def median_split(data, line_number):
```

where data is my 2d numpy array and line_number the, well, number of the line in which I calculate the median value.
The function should then return two 2d numpy arrays where one has only values <= median value in the given line and the other one only values > the median value.

My Question now is, is there some sort of included filtering function in numpy and if not, what is the most practical way to achieve this goal?
I mean I could iterate over each column, make the comparison and then concatenate the column to another 2d numpy array, but that somehow does not feel very ellegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.median` to find the median and then `np.wheres` to find where the indices are bigger than said value. (I assume your arrays are sorted in axis 1 or the median makes no sense anyway).

I think this is what you want, though I'm a little confused as to what output you want. Feel free to clarify and leave a comment if this isn't right.

```
def median_split(data, line_number):

    row = data[line_number, :]
    median = np.median(row)
    wheres = np.where(median <= row)[0]  # only one axis so get index 0
    col = wheres[0]  # just get the first one

    return data[:, :col], data[:, col:]
```

Feel free to optimize and shorten this, I chose clarity over efficiency.

Comment: if you switch median and row, then it works perefctly fine, thanks